# Blazor UserManager.GetUserAsync throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

`UserManager.GetUserAsync(authState.User)` is throwing an exception unless `UserManager` has already been called.

For example;

This throws a `NullReferenceException` on `await UserManager.GetUserAsync(authState.User)`;

```
@ page "/"
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

<AuthorizeView>
  ...
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
      var currentUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(authState.User); // exception here
    }
}
```

but this works OK;

```
@ page "/"
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

<AuthorizeView>
  ...
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      var allUsers = UserManager.Users.ToList(); // hack

      var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
      var currentUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(authState.User); // this is now working OK
    }
}
```

Why do I need to trigger `UserManager` before I can use the `GetUsersAsync` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SignInManager<TUser>` and `UserManager<TUser>` aren't supported in Razor components.

[See source...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Dang. I must have read that about a thousand times, but it never landed. Do you know what is the correct approach for getting to the IdentityUser from the ClaimsPrincipal?

Comment: Could you please tell me what you were trying to get at, and I'll try to find a viable solution...

Comment: I was trying to get back the `IdentityUser` (as in most examples on the net I have overridden this as `ApplicationUser`)

Answer (score 5):

The reason they are not supported is they are only available on the server. The real cause of your problem here is your not providing the `UserManager<>` for injection.

Note: `IdentityUser` is the base class for users. The template does not provide ApplicationUser that inherits this.

So in `Startup.cs`

```
 services.AddTransient<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@currentUser?.Email

@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    ApplicationUser currentUser;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        if (authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            currentUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(authState.User); // exception was here
        }
    }
}
```