# Blazor Server: "System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following `OnAfterRenderAsync` function in my blazor page:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    try
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeDropZone");

            var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;


            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userSecurityInfo = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(user);
                var userDbImages = (await ImageData.GetImagesByUser(userSecurityInfo.Id)).ToList();
                foreach (var dbImage in userDbImages)
                {
                    _userFiles.Add(new ImageModel()
                    {
                        ID = dbImage.ID,
                        DatasetName = dbImage.DatasetName,
                        Name = dbImage.FileName,
                        UploadDate = dbImage.UploadDate,
                        BucketUrl = dbImage.BucketUrl,
                        BucketUrlExpireDate = dbImage.BuckeUrlExpireDate
                    });
                }
            }
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnAfterRenderError (DataManagement):" + e.Message);
    }
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);

    return;
}
```

While normally this operation is quite fast (it only loads image URLs instead of actual image data) after the first startup of the server it takes a bit. If the user decides to change pages while the operation is still running I get the following error:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'WebApplication.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
> System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync() System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913. at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

- The second page in this case also has some similar db operation
- The actual data accession is not done in the EF database ASP.NET creates automatically, I store my actual data in a separate MS SQL database, which is accessed using dapper.
- There are some similar posts on SO, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046008/blazor-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-operation-co). The answer suggest to use a * `DbContextFactory`. However, I have tried the suggested code, but with that my application crashes during startup with a `System.AggregateException`. I don't fully understand why.
- I don't quite understand, why there is a problem with multiple EF accesses, as I only access  the security DB very shortly to get the user ID. This should in theory be done long before the user has the chance to switch pages.

Any suggestions on how to fix this and understand the issue better are appreciated. So far I simply catch the exception, so the application doesn't crash, but I would like to prevent it in the first place.

Comment: You should not use `UserManager` in a Razor component. Do implement the DbContextFactory object, even of the issue does not directly related to not using it.

Comment: "You should not use UserManager in a Razor component" - Why not and what should I use instead to determine the userid of a logged-in user?

Comment: The UserManager was not designed to work in a Razor components, just as HttpContext was not designed to work in Blazor.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64432268/6152891 `what should I use instead to determine the userid of a logged-in user`: claims

Comment: @enet Ah ok, so it really is just the UserManager, not AuthenticationStateProvider. I didn't use usermanager in a version before, but liked it's usage more than `user.FindFirst(u => u.Type.Contains("nameidentifier"))?.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this line:

```
var userDbImages = (await ImageData.GetImagesByUser(userSecurityInfo.Id)).ToList();
```

is still executing on the DbContext when you change page, so whatever DB call gets made on the new page it fails because the only DbContext is already in use.  I'm guesssing because at this point I don't know what `ImageData` is!

The DbContext Factory solves these problems, so you need to sort out what issues you have with implementing the Factory because you can't run async database operations against a single context in a real application.  Post a question on your Factory problem and we will see if we can help.

A further comment on design: use a scoped view service to hold the image data so you only get it once: ignore if I'm reading this code wrongly and you are already doing so in `ImageData`.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. What I'm curious about is, that this line accesses a different database than the EF Core database, that comes with the default Asp.net identity. This is my own database accessed via dapper.

Comment: NP. The error says:  "An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'WebApplication.Data.ApplicationDbContext'. System.InvalidOperationException:".  Which database is `ApplicationDbContext`?  Your identity or application database.

Comment: I guess so, at least I'm handling all the access to the other databases myself and I'm not aware of ever using a DBContext class. Forgive the probably stupid question, but I was thinking this was only needed for code-first databases? The other database is a db-first database.

Comment: All my projects are DB First, and all use DBContextFactory for DbContext management.  If you haven't read this MS-Docs article, do so.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/